# Extra spacing above and below text-type input

Tags: css, html

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/yDQXG/

What I see in Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEw56.png

I can't seem to figure out where the spacing around the input element (blue fields) is coming from. Any ideas?

```
<form method="get">
<fieldset class="halfblock">
    <input class="blockheader" type="text" value="Field A">
    <textarea class="blocktext" rows="5">Line 1&#13;&#10;Line 2</textarea>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: external style sheet would be far more better option since you can cache it ...so page loading speed would be faster

Comment: @NullPointer, I'm sure that this is just an example. Your comment isn't really contributing to a solution or helping to clarify the question.

Comment: Please only show *relevant* code in the future.

Comment: @Mikuso what do you mean ? i commented (1st ) i think it may help the user not in that answer but useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because they are inline elements. Same thing happens often with images.

All you need to do is add `display:block` to your inputs:

```
input.blockheader {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ABD9E2;
    font: 11px/11px 'Vollkorn', serif;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    /* top: -7px; */

    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, this won't work for firefox if you are dealing with widths issues, the display block on your input will cause the input to overflow its container. @KingKingFrog answer below worked great for me.

Answer (score 7):

set line-height: 0px; on .halfblock

```
.quote_body .halfblock {
    width: 262px;
    border: 1px dotted 
    #333;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yup, check the `line-height`.

Answer (score 3):

Add the [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) tag to the input's CSS:

```
input.blockheader {
    display: block;
}
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Set:

.halfblock & .thirdblock to:

```
line-height:0px
```

Also consider the option of adding a CSS reset

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/